# JavaFx Media player status is null after initialisation

Tags: java, javafx

After initialisation of a `Media` and a `MediaPlayer` for a file (see code below), the MediaPlayer status is null.

Nowhere in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html) I read that this status can be null and what's the meaning of it.
I expected it to be "UNKNOWN" or "READY" but not null.

What's the rational (or the error) behind this ?

The Media and MediaPlayer initialisation code:

```
private void configure() {

    synchronized (lock) {
        media=null;
        player=null;
        configured = true;
        if (!clAudioFileAnalyzer.isJavaFixInitialized())
            return;

        playable = true;
        String fileStr = null;
        try {
            fileStr = this.file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            formatException = ex;
            logger.error("Error when accessing the media : " + formatException.getLocalizedMessage());
            playable = false;
            PlayerEvent event = new PlayerEvent(this, PlayerStatus.ERROR, 0, formatException);
            firePlayerEvent(event);
        }
        if (fileStr != null) {
            try {
                media = new Media(fileStr);
            } catch (MediaException ex) {
                formatException = ex;
            }
            if ((media != null) && (media.getError() != null)) {
                formatException = media.getError();
            }
            if (formatException != null) {
                logger.error("Error when peparing media for playing: " + formatException.getLocalizedMessage());
                playable = false;
                PlayerEvent event = new PlayerEvent(this, PlayerStatus.ERROR, 0, formatException);
                firePlayerEvent(event);
            }
            else {
                media.setOnError(() -> {
                    formatException = media.getError();
                    logger.error("Error when peparing media for playing: " + formatException.getLocalizedMessage());
                    playable = false;
                    PlayerEvent event = new PlayerEvent(this, PlayerStatus.ERROR, 0, formatException);
                    firePlayerEvent(event);
                });
                try {
                    player = new MediaPlayer(media);
                } catch (MediaException ex) {
                    formatException = ex;
                }
                if ((player != null) && (player.getError() != null)) {
                    formatException = player.getError();
                }
                if (formatException != null) {
                    logger.error("Error when peparing player for playing: " + formatException.getLocalizedMessage());
                    playable = false;
                    PlayerEvent event = new PlayerEvent(this, PlayerStatus.ERROR, 0, formatException);
                    firePlayerEvent(event);
                }
                else {
                    player.setOnError(() -> {
                        formatException = player.getError();
                        logger.error("Error when peparing player for playing: " + formatException.getLocalizedMessage());
                        playable = false;
                        PlayerEvent event = new PlayerEvent(this, PlayerStatus.ERROR, 0, formatException);
                        firePlayerEvent(event);
                    });

                    logger.debug("Player initialized, with status " + player.statusProperty().toString()); // Ouputs NULL !!
                    player.statusProperty().addListener(this::statusInvalidated);
                    player.currentTimeProperty().addListener(this::positionInvalidated);
                    player.setOnEndOfMedia(this::onEndOfMedia);
                    player.setOnStopped(() -> {logger.info("--On Stop--");
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The reason why I'm looking at that status is that from time to time, both the MediaPlayer `stop()` and `play()` method get stuck. No error, but no sound, status changes, ... So I was investigating the status of the player when this occurs.

-- Subsidiary question:
Better use one MediaPlayer by file to play or reuse a single static MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the player under the else clause. The player under the else clause is first invoked before being intialized under the try clause. Try this

- Reinitialize the player class before invoking. This will probably involve you cleaning up your if clauses a bit.
- Or just initiliaze the player to a new player instead of initializing it to null. This way at least any player instance invoked will already be declared and therefore the error will disappear.
  Happy coding.

Comment: Actually, I don't get what you mean "Reinitialize the player class before invoking" or "Or just initiliaze the player to a new player instead of initializing it to null". I don't see how I could initialize the player earlier in that code. I'll do it as soon as I have a valid Media. How would suggest to do that earlier ?